# Удалить кортежи из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, коллекции

Имеется список кортежей следующего вида:

```
spam = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 5), (5, 4), (1, 4)]
```

Предположим, что я хочу удалить из списка все кортежи, нулевой элемент которых равен 1. Т.е. должен получиться следующий список:

```
spam = [(2, 5), (5, 4)]
```

пробовал сделать через цикл:

```
for item in spam:
     if item[0] == 1:
         spam.remove(item)
```

Но в таком случае некоторые элементы пропускаются. Понимаю, что эту задачу легко решить используя два списка:

```
eggs = []
for item in spam:
    if item[0] != 1:
        eggs.append(item)
```

По сути мы просто сформируем новый список, содержащий только нужные элементы. Но можно ли решить эту задачу без использования второго списка?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первые два варианта создают новый список используя условие и данные старого списка, их привел в ответ как самые канонично-питоничьи.

Третий вариант, изменяет старый список.

```
spam = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 5), (5, 4), (1, 4)]

new_spam = [x for x in spam if x[0] != 1]
print(new_spam)  # [(2, 5), (5, 4)]

new_spam = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] != 1, spam))
print(new_spam)  # [(2, 5), (5, 4)]
```

Или циклом, но чтобы проблем с индексами не было, нужно удалять с конца:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(spam))):
    if spam[i][0] == 1:
        spam.pop(i)

print(spam)  # [(2, 5), (5, 4)]
```

Comment: Получается, я могу сделать вот так `spam = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] != 1, spam))`, чтобы не создавать ещё один список?

Comment: Не, новый список все-равно будет создан там есть filter и list. А к чему беспокойство по поводу создания новых списков? :)

Comment: Ага, а если я буду использовать первый вариант `spam = [x for x in spam if x[0] != 1]`, то просто изменю существующий список?

Comment: нет, первый вариант тоже создает новый список, это генератор списка, видите в конструкции квадратные скобки? А вот третий вариант не создает новый список, изменяя текущий, но мне кажется что он излишен )

Comment: Понятно, по сути мы создаём в памяти новый объект, хотя и можем присвоить ссылку на него переменной spam.

Comment: Да, можно присвоить сразу же: `spam = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 5), (5, 4), (1, 4)]` `spam = [x for x in spam if x[0] != 1]`, тогда ссылка перепишется